# Is there another word that means 'togglable'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Using Merriam-Webster as a baseline, the word 'togglable' doesn't exist yet. It has made it into Wiktionary. It also makes enough intuitive sense that I don't have a problem using it. But, I'm wondering if a synonym exists. Is there another word that means "Able to be turned on and off"?

Comment: *togglable* is too much of a mouthful.

Comment: Using other online sources including Wiktionary and YourDictionary.com, both "togglable" and "toggleable" are words already in existence.

Comment: Kristina - Yep. I wasn't clear enough, but I saw it in Wiktionary. I'm still looking for another option since it's a mouthful as Tim points out. Being on the complicated side of pronunciation is what spawned the question.

Comment: Agreed, @AlanW.Smith! :-)

Comment: I ended up using selectable - worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will [switchable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/switch?q=switchable#switch__25) do?

> *The three separately switchable, compact fluorescent lamps in red, green and blue, not only produce these primary colours, but also three secondary-colour pastel shades and one shade of white.*

Comment: I think a toggle is a switch that alternates between only two states and in which the same input results in the toggle changing one of those states for the other. As when you have one button for "on" and "off" on your TV remote, and the TV takes so long to come on that you think you've not pressed the button hard enough, so you press it again and find you've just turned the TV off again! Am I right about "toggle"?

Comment: @MARGANA - You're right on with toggle being a state change between an on/off. Conceptually, it's binary. To add a little more to the request, I'm currently using the phrase "Togglable Synesthesia". "Switchable" seems to be the best alternative. Though, in my case, I think I'll stick with the nascent word.

Answer (score 0):

**Swappable** could work as an alternative.